# Song similar to David Bowie - "Ashes to Ashes"

Tags: melody

I have a track stuck in my head which I don't know the interpret nor the title.
Its very similiar to "David Bowie - Ashes to Ashes". I think on the label/logo was a vinyl.

Where can I find similar tracks based on the melody ?

It drives me nuts that I cant find what I'm looking for, especially that I don't know what to look for.

Comment: [musipedia.org](https://www.musipedia.org) is designed for exactly this.

Comment: @Aaron - I have generally had no luck with musipedia.org searches.

Comment: This may sound odd, but would you be willing to make this a separate answer instead of an edit to the question?  It helps the site if we know which questions have answers and which don't

Comment: @chris-sunami-supports-monica sure, is this ok/good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The track i was looking for is: "LCD Soundsystem - american dream".
I found a screenshot on my old phone that i have made when i heard the track the first time on the radio :)

> 

*Note: Answer created as wished by @chris-sunami-supports-monica*

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. If you could, can you come back in about a day and mark this as accepted?  (The system won't allow you to accept your own answer immediately).

Comment: Sure, no problem. I hope i dont forget about it, but as i dayli visit SO, i think about it :)